# using logstash with Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash

I am looking at implementing ES using logstash and Sql server as my data source. I was initially using river to read data from Sql server but one of the developers in my team recommended looking at using logstash. Can anyone point to a guide on how to get started with logstash & sql server. My goal is to do search using elasticsearch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, there is not any Logstash API for reading SQL.
For input API supported, you can visit [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.2/) to get more information

For my recommendation, you can write a program to read from sql and write to a file. Then use logstash [file](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.2/inputs/file)
API to read from the file. The Logstash website has getting started tutorial. It is easy to learn.
Good Luck

Comment: You should be able to use jdbc plugin with JDBC driver from Microsoft, I'm working on it now, no luck yet though.

Comment: @PiotrOwsiak any news about the logstash-JDBC sql server connection through input plugin?