# Can logstash extract log saving in oracle?

Tags: logstash

My application use oralce as DB server, and all logs of the application store in oracle too.
I install logstash in my oracle server and config as shipper.
How can I config logstash to extract logs in oralce? Is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, there is no any input plugin for oracle. You can write a program to query out the logs and then save to a file. Then you use [logstash input file](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/inputs/file) to import the logs to logstash.

For example, you can write Java program with [oracle api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html) to get the logs

Comment: What about other db server? Why noby develop that kind of plugin? There isn't much requirement about pulling log from oracle?

Comment: Someone also have ask this kind question before. Maybe need to wait the logstash development team to publish it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985299/using-logstash-with-sql-server/20988507#20988507